# C# ASP issue with Excel connection

Tags: c#

I have a C# ASP application and it connects with Excel, but when I run the application I receive this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

I was suggested to install this driver : AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe , 
I  installed the driver but still I receive the same message and the application breaks.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: There are a number of questions about this error on Stack Overflow, some with many answers besides that one, have you tried them? ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](//stackoverflow.com/q/6649363); ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)](//stackoverflow.com/q/40360932); [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine while data export to MS ACCESS](//stackoverflow.com/q/17716207)...

Comment: is it a x64 or x86 machine?

Comment: It is important to clarify that I have installed Office 2016, Windows 10 for 64 bits hardware